# Packaging nodejs applications for commercial purposes

Tags: node.js, compilation, package

How do we create a package of a nodejs console application which is -

1. Easily installable, just download and run from console.
2. User does not have to install nodejs and dependent lib which are used in the app.
3. User has no access to the code. He can only run the app. He should not be able to tamper the code.
4. Runs on multiple operating systems.